# LINQ Rollback in Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, linq, rollback

Veiculo veiculo = new Veiculo();

```
                    veiculo.codigoUsuario = usuario.codigoUsuario;
                    veiculo.codigoTipoVeiculo = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoVeiculo.SelectedValue);
                    veiculo.codigoTipoMarca = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoMarca.SelectedValue);
                    veiculo.codigoTipoModelo = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoModelo.SelectedValue);
                    veiculo.codigoTipoCombustivel = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoCombustivel.SelectedValue);
                    veiculo.codigoTipoCambio = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoCambio.SelectedValue);
                    //veiculo.codigoTipoVersao = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoVersao.SelectedValue);
                    veiculo.AnoFabricacao = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDataFabricacao.SelectedValue);
                    veiculo.AnoModelo = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDataModelo.SelectedValue);
                    veiculo.Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(txtValor.Text);
                    veiculo.Cor = ddlCor.SelectedValue;
                    veiculo.Portas = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPortas.SelectedValue);
                    veiculo.Destaque = true;
                    veiculo.Ativo = true;
                    veiculo.Kilometragem = txtKilometragem.Text;
                    veiculo.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
                    veiculo.DataVencimento = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);

                    try
                    {
                        ctx.AddToVeiculo(veiculo);
                        ctx.SaveChanges();

                        AdicionarOpcionais(veiculo);

                        SaveImage(FUImagemPrincipal, veiculo);
                        SaveImage(FUSegundaImagem, veiculo);
                        SaveImage(FUTerceiraImagem, veiculo);
                        SaveImage(FUQuartaImagem, veiculo);
                        SaveImage(FUQuintaImagem, veiculo);
                        SaveImage(FUSextaImagem, veiculo);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
```

**THE SAVE IMAGE METHOD**

```
private void SaveImage(FileUpload FileUpload, Veiculo veiculo)
{
    // Upload Original Image Here
    string uploadFileName = "";
    string uploadFilePath = "";
    VeiculoImagem veiculoImagem = new VeiculoImagem();

    if (FileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(FUImagemPrincipal.FileName).ToLower();
        if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".png")
        {
            uploadFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
            uploadFilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/upload"), uploadFileName);
            try
            {
                veiculoImagem.Url = "/upload/" + uploadFileName;
                veiculoImagem.codigoVeiculo = veiculo.codigoVeiculo;

                ctx.AddToVeiculoImagem(veiculoImagem);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

                FileUpload.SaveAs(uploadFilePath);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Alert.Visible = true;
                lbAlert.Text = "Erro, tente novamente.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Alert.Visible = true;
            lbAlert.Text = "Tipo de arquivo selecionado não permitido.";
        }
    }
}
```

How  do i rollback if dont save the images (enter on else)? Because it save the veiculo, but dont save the images...

I don't know if my question is clearly... But please, help me!

Comment: See [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) - this can be used to easily add 'begin/commit/rollback' transaction support at the database level.

Comment: I know about TransactionScope. But it will work in another method? Like i'm doing... I make SubmitOnChanges on Veiculo, and SubmitOnChanges into Save image and put the submit in the end of Veiculo?

Comment: If it is inside the same TransactionScope's .. *dynamic stack* scope, then yes. If it isn't, make it so. (This is simply how TransactionScpes fundamentally work.)